# Netfilterqueue, set_payload does not change packet with python3

Tags: python-3.x, iptables, scapy

I am trying to alter raw.load in a UDP packet using NetfilterQueue (ver. 0.8.1) and Python3 (ver. 3.7.3). Scapy ver. is 2.4.4

Destination server runs tcpdump to sniff incoming packets but nothing arrives.

My script can capture packets from nfqueue without problems. I change [Raw].load with a new text and set back with set_payload but no results.

```
from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue
from scapy.all import *
import binascii

def print_and_accept(pkt):
    pkt_scapy = scapy.all.IP(pkt.get_payload())
    pkt_scapy[scapy.all.Raw].load="new text goes here"
    del pkt_scapy[scapy.all.IP].len
    del pkt_scapy[scapy.all.UDP].chksum
    del pkt_scapy[scapy.all.IP].chksum
    
    pkt.set_payload(bytes(pkt_scapy))

    pkt.accept()

nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
nfqueue.bind(1, print_and_accept)
try:
    nfqueue.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('')

nfqueue.unbind()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it seems netfilterqueue is kind of obsolete. For your case i suggest you just drop by default the packets and instead of packet.accept() use scapy's send() function :

```
def print_and_accept(pkt):
    pkt_scapy = scapy.all.IP(pkt.get_payload())
    pkt_scapy[scapy.all.Raw].load="new text goes here"
    del pkt_scapy[scapy.all.IP].len
    del pkt_scapy[scapy.all.UDP].chksum
    del pkt_scapy[scapy.all.IP].chksum

pkt.drop()
send(pkt_scapy)
```